# Duvida sobre tabela de estados e cidades

Tags: c#, desempenho

Amigos bom dia.
Estou com uma duvida, sobre a melhor forma de preencher uma combobox com as informaçoes de Estado e outro com a informaçoes de cidade.

Minha duvida, consiste em, oque seria melhor em questao de desempenho, ou em questao de boas praticas?? ter uma tabela no banco, e sempre que executar o form, ele consulta o banco? ou definir essa tabela diretamente no codigo, pois os estados nao vao mudar e as cidades tambem não.

valeu

Comment: Caso opte pelo banco você pode rodar esse [Sql](http://samus.com.br/web/site/artigo-todas_as_cidades_do_brasil_atualizado_e_com_acentos)

Comment: Marconi, perfeito. muito bom isso em. obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Claro que, em termos de desempenho, é melhor se a informação estiver definida directamente no código, pois evita a comunicação com a base de dados ou outra qualquer estrutura que a disponibilize.

Falando de boas práticas, por norma, definir estruturas "hard coded" não é uma boa prática, pois sempre que for preciso alterar algo, é necessário também compilar a aplicação.

Por fim, tudo depende dos seus requisitos e do que a aplicação, em si, exige.

Comment: Legal André, valeu pelo esclarecimento.